# Find the maximum possible value of a natural number 'p' such that $8p^3+50$ is divisible by $2p+5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find the maximum possible value of a natural number 'p' such that $8p^3+50$ is divisible by $2p+5$

what is given in the solution since I couldn't solve it on my own

$2p+5=0$

$p=-5/2$

$8(-5/2)^3+50=-75$

Hence it should be divided by $35$

I did not understand this. Can anyone explain it to me using any example? Or any other method. I will be really thankful

Answer (score 1):

The solution uses this concept. Note that, for **any real** $p$,
$$8p^3+50 =(2p+5)f(p) + r,$$ where $f(p)$ is the quotient, and $r$ is the remainder after division of $8p^3+50$  by $2p+5$. The solution first computes $r(p)$ by putting $p=-5/2$. In particular,
$$8(-5/2)^3+50 = r + f(p)\times 0=r=-75.$$
Consequently, $8p^3+50 -r = 8p^3+125$ is divisible by $2p+5$ for **all real values of** $p$.

But the question asks for finding the maximum **integer** that divides $8p^3+50$. In other words, $8p^3+50 = (2p+5) k$, where $k$ is an integer. But $8p^3+50 +75 = (2p+5)f(p)$. Therefore, $(2p+5)k + 75 = (2p+5)f(p)$ implies $75 = (2p+5)(f(p)-k)$.

In other words, $2p+5$ must divide $75$. Consequently, the greatest value of $p$ such that $2p+5$ divides $75$ is computed as $2p+5=75$, or $p=35$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** [from](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/specfact2.htm) $$8p^3+50=8p^3+125 - 75=(2p)^3+5^3-75=\color{red}{\left(2p+5\right)}\left((2p)^2-2p\cdot5+5^2\right)-75$$
If we want $2p+5 \mid 8p^3+50$ then we conclude that $2p+5 \mid 75$ and $p$ can range from $0$ to $35$.

Answer (score 0):

Divisible implies the ratio is an integer. Hence:
$$\frac{8p^3+50}{2p+5}=4p^2-10p+25-\frac{75}{2p+5}.$$
The right hand side is an integer if:
$$75|(2p+5) \ \ and \ \ 2p+5\le 75 \Rightarrow p\le 35.$$